# How do people who sell Bitcoin for fiat using Bisq know who paid them with bank transfer?

Tags: bisq

I've bought some Bitcoin for fiat using SEPA bank transfer via Bisq.

The Bisq application now actively tells you to NOT put any identifier whatsoever in the "message/OCR field" when making the international bank transfer. It used to tell you to put in a random string of letters given by the Bisq application, to identify to the receiver who has paid.

But now, they only have the amount to go by. What if two people buy the same amount of Bitcoin from the same seller, and only one of them pays? How will they now determine who has paid and who did not?

Before you say "they look at the name", at least my bank does never tell me the name of the person making a payment.

Answer (score 0):

> But now, they only have the amount to go by. What if two people buy the same amount of Bitcoin from the same seller, and only one of them pays? How will they now determine who has paid and who did not?

Every bank transaction has a reference number associated with it.

Comment: Prayank: Read the question before "answering".

Comment: Alice received 1000 USD in two transactions, one was sent by Bob and other Carol. Would Carol be able to share transaction number for 1000 USD sent by Bob?

Comment: More information: https://bisq.wiki/Dispute_resolution

Comment: on bisq you know the fiat bank account number of the buyer, so you can check who of the 2 paid you